# decompile .NET Replace method (v4.6.1)

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace, decompiler

I want to see how the

```
public String Replace(String oldValue, String newValue);
```

method that is inside mscorlib.dll (System.String) works.

I decompiled the mscorlib.dll with dotPeek and inside the method there is a call to ReplaceInternal method which I cannot find it

```
string s = ReplaceInternal(oldValue, newValue);
```

I have search for this method even on the open source .NET Core from GIT but no luck.

[image: View my Decompiled code]

Please explain where is this method and what is inside?

Comment: [`ReplaceInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,35ab9efe11757286) ist `extern`, so most likely it is implemented as "unmanaged", native C++ code. See [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) for details.

Comment: btw you dont need to decompile, you can see the source @ http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,69fc1d0aa6df8a90

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extern C++ code is here.

[https://github.com/gbarnett/shared-source-cli-2.0/blob/master/clr/src/vm/comstring.cpp](https://github.com/gbarnett/shared-source-cli-2.0/blob/master/clr/src/vm/comstring.cpp#L1572)

Line 1578 has

```
FCIMPL3(Object*, COMString::ReplaceString, StringObject* thisRefUNSAFE, StringObject* oldValueUNSAFE, StringObject* newValueUNSAFE)
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1014073/Fastest-method-to-trim-all-whitespace-from-Strings?fid=1888684&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Thread&spc=Relaxed&fr=76

Answer (score 6):

Having a look [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,35ab9efe11757286,references), you will notice this:

```
// This method contains the same functionality as StringBuilder Replace. 
// The only difference is that
// a new String has to be allocated since Strings are immutable
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private extern String ReplaceInternal(String oldValue, String newValue);
```

The `extern` keyword [means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx.) that this method is implemented externally, in another dll.

That being said, it may be even written in a not managed dll (in C++ quite possibly), that is used by this module. So you can't decompile this code or see it, as you usually do with managed code.

**Update**

After a little searching I found the corresponding code in the coreclr project:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp

Comment: Thank you very much, but where is the "another.dll" ? I want to see inside .. or what is his name?

Answer (score 0):

To see how the function works, take a look at the reference source under http://referencesource.microsoft.com/.

Serach for `mscorlib`, go to `System.String`, serach for `Replace` and look: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,69fc1d0aa6df8a90,references